# Clean Google Analytics referral spam in my web app

Tags: google-analytics

Stats have been showing many referrals of spam crawlers. I have solved the problem doing a segment in Reports and in my Google analytics panel now the stats are “clean” without any disturbing data….

I want to know if there is something I can do to show this clean data also in my web app because now the data is full of rubbish referrals.

How I can filter them. are there any APIs which send me filtered data in queries ?

Answer (score 0):

You can block the spam referrals by adding a filter.

In GA, got to the Admin tab. Then go to Filters (under the View column). Name the filter, select "Custom" and "Exclude". In the Filter Field dropdown, select "Campaign Source" and enter the domain of the spam referrer in the Filter Pattern box.

Click verify and it should show that referrals that were previously tracked will now be counted as 0 hits.

You can add multiple domains to the filter pattern using regex, like:

`(domainone|domaintwo|domainthree)`

Unfortunately, this will not retroactively change your past data.